# Is there a way to add conversion operators to primitive types?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, casting, operator-overloading

Is there a way to add conversion operators to primitive types?

For example:

```
Someclass x = (Someclass)7; //or even implicit casting
```

I know that it's possible to make a ctor in `someclass` that accepts an int, but is there a way to add a conversion operator to int instead?

Comment: No, that is impossible

Comment: The code you provided compiles if SomeClass has a constructor that takes an int. "is there a way to add a conversion operator to int instead" doesn't make sense unless you mean "I want to do `int x = SomeClass c;`"

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe You are missing "I know that it's possible to make a ctor in someclass that accepts an int, but is there a way to add a conversion operator to int instead?
"

Comment: @DieterLücking Yep, I got thrown off by the sample code line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code

```
SomeClass x = (SomeClass)7;
```

compiles if SomeClass has a constructor that accepts an int:

```
struct SomeClass {
    SomeClass(int) {}
};

int main() {
    SomeClass x = (SomeClass)7;
}
```

If you want to be able to convert a SomeClass into an integer, you want operator int()

```
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass {
    int m_n;

public:
    SomeClass(int n_) : m_n(n_) {}
    SomeClass() : m_n(0) {}

    operator int () { return m_n; }
};

int main() {
    SomeClass x = 7; // The cast is not required.
    std::cout << (int)x << "\n";
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/fwija0

Without the constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass {
    int m_n;

public:
    SomeClass() : m_n(123) {}

    operator int () { return m_n; }
};

int main() {
    SomeClass x;
    std::cout << (int)x << "\n";
}
```

http://ideone.com/xfsdjp

If you are asking "how can I convert int to SomeClass with a conversion operator" the closest thing is `operator=`

```
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass {
public:
    int m_n;
    SomeClass() : m_n(0) {}
    SomeClass& operator = (int n) { m_n = n; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    SomeClass sc;
    std::cout << "sc.m_n = " << sc.m_n << "\n";
    sc = 5;
    std::cout << "sc.m_n = " << sc.m_n << "\n";
}
```

http://ideone.com/wDl4oP

Comment: I would not condone using `operator int` since it's an implicit conversion to `int` that can be invoked in many situations where it's undesirable. I don't think this is what the OP is asking about but `explicit operator int` would be the safer way to proceed.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/XXhwsM) the `<< (int) x` cast isn't required but [here](http://ideone.com/f7UjuP) the cast is required.

Comment: Never have implicit conversions from and to a type - either make the constructor or the operator T explicit

Comment: I asked if this was possible without a ctor that accepts an int.

Comment: @kuhaku Are you asking for a conversion operator that converts *from int to SomeClass*? You can write an 'operator=(int)'.

Comment: @kuhaku example `operator=` added.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is impossible. You can not change operations on primitive (builtin) types.